# jQuery .css(): is there an intrinsic delay in a property's application to an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am applying CSS changes to elements live in a jQuery plugin I wrote. I do some arithmetic utilizing the sizing of containing elements, and I keep getting inconsistent values that seems like it stems from a race condition.

Here's the code:

```
    $.each( $marquee.find('li'), function(){

        console.log('li count');

        var $li = $(this);

        $li.css({
            display: 'inline'
        });
    });

    var sectionWidth = $marquee.outerWidth();
    var containerWidth = $wrappingDiv.width();

    console.log( sectionWidth );
    console.log( containerWidth );
```

The values reported in the console logs vary wildly on page refreshes, and I can't figure out why. Any insight into this, and any way to make it work consistently?

**Edit:** I set up a JSFiddle scenario, but as I suspected (because JSFiddle's shell handles rendering differently than an actual browser), it doesn't replicate the scenario above. Not sure what use it will be to diagnosis, but here's the link.

http://jsfiddle.net/BJedD/27/

**Addendum** This appears to be happening solely in Webkit browsers.

Comment: Can you setup a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) showing the problem?

Comment: I would be nice if you can share your code via JsFiddle.net, so we can help better :-)

Comment: I added the JSFiddle link to the question, but as I said, I'm not sure it's an accurate representation of the issue, and would implore one to try it locally.

Comment: I'm getting constant results. Any change that you've got dynamic/external content, such as images in your real code?

Comment: Rob: Nope. Everything is CSS-only. Are you testing locally in Webkit? This isn't the first time I've run into this issue.

Comment: I ran the jsfiddle you created a bunch of times and it's the same each time.  I'm using latest Chrome, which is WebKit.

Answer (score 1):

Do this after `$(window).load(function(){//Your code})` instead of `$(document).ready(function(){//Your code})`. I have tried this in your jsFiddle and it works (consistent results).